# magento 2 captcha not rendering if I override layout xml

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override contact us page from one column to 2-columns-left

what I have did is copy **contact_index_index.xml** from `vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\layout\`

to

`app\design\frontend\namespace\themename\Magento_Contact\layout\`

and change layout to  `layout="2columns-left"` so my xml is like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

everything working fine and it changes template to 2 columns left but some how captcha is not rendering. Is it bug or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway I have solved it myself.The captcha is not rendering due to I haven't override captcha layout xml so overriding it to your theme will solved issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and just overriding the captcha layout it was solved. Just what you said.
 For more help, my code is

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Entrepids\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Entrepids_Contact::form.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
            <action method="setFormId">
                <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">contact_us</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setImgWidth">
                <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setImgHeight">
                <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Nice! That solved my problem with the captcha not showing